# CKEDITOR - Uncaught Error: The specified element mode is not supported on element: "meta"

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor, textarea, meta

This error appears when I try to use 2 editors in the same page...

I load the content from a DB using PHP. If $_POST isset, I load the content from the specific $_POST value.

The code works fine for 1 only textarea-ckeditor, the problem appears when I use 2 different editors getting this error: Uncaught Error: The specified element mode is not supported on element: "meta".

```
<div class="form_group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

           <label class="formlabel">Body</label><br>

                <?php if(isset($_POST['body'])){ ?> 

                <textarea class="ckeditor" name="body"> <?php echo $_POST['body']; ?> </textarea>

                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'body' ,{
                    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                    filebrowserUploadUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&editor=ckeditor&fldr='
                    });
                </script>

                <?php } else { ?>

                 <textarea class="ckeditor" id="ckeditorb" name="body" value="<?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($art['BODY']));?>" ></textarea>

                <?php $body_content=json_encode(utf8_encode($art['BODY'])); ?>

                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'body' ,{
                    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                    filebrowserUploadUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&editor=ckeditor&fldr='
                    });
                    CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditorb.setData(<?php echo $body_content; ?>, function(){
                        this.checkDirty(); // true
                    });
                </script>

                <?php } ?>

            <?php if(isset($error['body']) && !empty($error['body'])){ 
                echo $error['body'];
             }  ?>
        </div>



        <div class="form_group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

           <label class="formlabel">Description</label><br>

                <?php if(isset($_POST['description'])){ ?> 

                <textarea class="ckeditor" name="description" id="descripcion_1"> <?php echo $_POST['description']; ?> </textarea>

                <?php $content=json_encode(utf8_decode($_POST['DESCRIPTION'])); ?>

                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' ,{
                    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                    filebrowserUploadUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&editor=ckeditor&fldr='
                    });
                    CKEDITOR.instances.descripcion_1.setData(<?php echo $content; ?>, function(){
                        this.checkDirty(); // true
                    });
                </script>

                <?php } else { ?>

                 <textarea class="ckeditor" id="descripcion_2" name="description" value="<?php echo $art['DESCRIPTION']; ?>" ></textarea>

                <?php $content=json_encode(utf8_decode($art['DESCRIPTION'])); ?>

                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' ,{
                    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                    filebrowserUploadUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '../ResposiveFilemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&editor=ckeditor&fldr='
                    });
                    CKEDITOR.instances.descripcion_2.setData(<?php echo $content; ?>, function(){
                        this.checkDirty(); // true
                    });
                </script>

                <?php } ?>

            <?php if(isset($error['description']) && !empty($error['description'])){ 
                echo $error['description'];
             }  ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same problem. It is related to the name of the textarea: description as there is a meta tag with the same name. Once you change the name of the textarea it would work.

Answer (score 0):

The ckeditor Plugin will read the tags which has the name of description . if you have any meta tag with name of description please remove the meta tag the ckeditor will work on your textarea with name of description.